# unable to render image using the <h:graphicImage> syntax of JSF 2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm looking for some help in using the  of JSF 2. I want to display an image in a webpage, but the image comes from a resource folder in my project directory structure. The problem is, the webpage doesn't load the image.

Here is my project directory structure

[image: project directory structure]

My code to load the image into the webpage

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="captain america.jpg"/>
```

when I run my code, it doesn't display the image. How can I load my images *from* *a resource folder* *to* *the webpage*?

Comment: You should use something like this  `<h:graphicImage value="../resources/images/image_name.png"  />` better not to put space in the name

Answer (score -2):

Use the value attribute

And image folder should be in root level same as that of web inf

Comment: I added the image folder in the web-inf location. web-inf--resources--images, I used the value attribute <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/captain america.jpg"></h:graphicImage>, but still the image is not being rendered.